# This is an invalid webresource request. javascript datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

Hi I have a datetimepicker for one of the textbox control see below the code

```
<script src="../client-scripts/date-picker.js" type="text/javascript">



"<td class="datafieldTBL" align="left">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtenddate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EndDate")%>'></asp:TextBox>
  onclick="javascript:displayDatePicker('<%=formViewUser.FindControl("txtenddate").ClientID %>');return false;"
</a> 
</td>"
```

Now the problem is moving from one page to another page where the above code is used while debugging the third time on the above code before it actually displays the second page an error is throw

> "This is an invalid webresource
>   request"
>
> "This is an invalid webresource
>   request."}
>       System.Web.HttpException: {"This is an invalid webresource request."}
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       HelpLink: Nothing
>       InnerException: Nothing
>       Message: "This is an invalid webresource request."
>       Source: "System.Web"
>       StackTrace: "   at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)"
>       TargetSite: {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}

Am not sure why this happens only third time on

```
"<a href="#" onclick="javascript:displayDatePicker('<%=formViewUser.FindControl("txtenddate").ClientID %>');return false;">"
```

?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe it after carefully debugging the app i figured out that the error culprit was a CustomControl Validator, i simply stopped using it and created my own validation and everything worked fine after.

Thanks
Gauls